# Asus Keyboard not working anymore after windows 10 update

Tags: windows, keyboard, asus-laptop

After updating my windows 10 to the latest version (KB4512508), my keyboard is not working anymore. My Laptop Model is Asus Gaming ROG GL502VMK.
I do lot of things like uninstalling the driver and install it again, etc but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Can it be used in safe mode? I consider that you could try to uninstall KB4512508 to test. This appears to be Microsoft's latest update in August, with possible compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KB4512508](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512508/windows-10-update-kb4512508)
brings no new features and only offers a few bug fixes and performance improvements.
It is not essential, so you may uninstall it and block it as described in the
Microsoft article
[How to temporarily prevent a Windows Update from reinstalling in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3183922/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-windows-update-from-reinstalling-in-windo).
A detailed how-to article can be found in
[How to prevent a specific Windows 10 Update or Driver from installing](https://www.repairwin.com/prevent-a-specific-windows-update-or-driver-from-installing-in-windows-10/).

However, before doing that, I would suggest to let Windows install its own
driver for the keyboard:

- Create a backup in the form of a
  [System Restore point](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4571-create-system-restore-point-windows-10-a.html),
  to be able to undo the following procedure
- Start Device Manager
- Open "Human Interface Devices" and find your problem keyboard
- Right-click the device and choose "Uninstall device"
- If given an option to delete the driver, choose it
- Reboot

If this does not help, you may also check if you need to install updates from the
[ASUS website](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-GL502VM/HelpDesk_Download/).
Only the drivers from 2019 are interesting.
There is also a
[BIOS update](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-GL502VM/HelpDesk_BIOS/)
that should be applied with extreme caution.